# poner limite de columnas que vizualiza una tabla en una pagina web

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, base-de-datos

tengo una tabla en mi proyecto el codigo es el siguiente

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
                                        <thead>
                                            <th hidden="" style="background: #FFFF00">SKU</th>
                                            <th style="background: #FFFF00">PRODUCTO</th>
                                            <th style="background: #FFFF00">PRECIO</th>
                                            <th style="background: #FFFF00">AÑADIR A LA VENTA</th>
                                        </thead>

                                        <tbody max=10 width="50" height="60" >
                                        <tr v-for="(producto,index) in filtroProducto">
                                            <td hidden="">@{{producto.sku}}</td>
                                            <td>@{{producto.nombre}}</td>
                                            <td> $@{{producto.precio}}</td>
                                            <div>
                                                <!--quiero pasar el valor del @{{producto.sku}} a la variable
                                                    v-model="sku" pero no se como 
                                                    para que en buscar producto me añada un producto
                                                    a la venta
                                                    estoy usando apiVenta.js-->

                                            <td><span class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"
                                        @click="aniadirProducto(producto.sku)">
                                            <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
                                        </span></td></div>

                                        <!--<button class="btn btn-sm" @click="editandoMascota(mascota.id_mascota)">
                                                    <i class="fas fa-pen"></i>
                                                </button>-->
                                        <!--<td><input type="number" v-model.number="cantidades[index]" min="1"></td>-->
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                    </table><!--fin tabla-->
```

el cual tiene como resultado la siguiente tabla
[image: datos]
el cual estoy buscando alguna clase o funcion que haga que unicamente me vizualize 3 columnas,
pero sin perder ningun dato ya que ya intente poner en el controlador un limite el cual funciona pero unicamente pasan los datos limites
por ejemplo si pongo de limite 3, unicamente pasan los 3 primeros valores y no pasan los otros 147 datos
existe alguna solucion que se aplique directamente sobre la tabla en html , css o en js?

Comment: Aun no tengo claro que preguntas, si confundes columnas con filas, la solución que buscas se llama "paginación"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quieres limitar a 3 columnas o filas? En cualquiera de los casos te recomiendo que instales un pluggin como Datatables y hay bastante documentación al respecto, en caso de que no puedas realizar alguna función te ayudo tengo bastante experiencia con ese pluggin